# I'm trying to wire a box that has 3 lines coming in from the top, one light, one fan, and I'm assuming the 3 rooms upstairs is the 3rd no more room

Tags: wiring, gfci

So, the three existing lines coming into bathroom are light, fan, and upstairs lights and of course the bottom is the main. I have a double switch(like 2 light switches on one, and gfci plug.. putting all in one box... Cannot get it to work! I keep popping breaker I don't know the wiring for it somehow. Currently only the bathroom that it's in works... I need help please

Comment: You need to properly trace the wires. It would be an outright fools errand to try and diagnose your problem over the Internet. I hope you took pictures before you dismantled everything.

Comment: Popping the breaker probably means you have a short.  Either a bare ground touching a hot screw or insulation broken on a hot wire touching ground(most common) or you rewired something wrong.  Also sounds like you need a bigger box.

Comment: Post a picture of the box with all the wires. Did you change something, add something new?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the inside of the box on the question please? And is it the circuit breaker that's tripping, or the GFCI?